# Racket hangs on Google Colab

Tags: ubuntu, installation, racket, google-colaboratory, freeze

Google Colab is good, runs not just Python, C++, and other langs too thru' the `%%script` blockmagic.

I'm trying to run Racket but it doesn't work, it hangs. Here's the content to run in Colab:

```
!sudo apt update -y
!sudo apt upgrade -y
!sudo apt install racket -y
#OK until here.

#Racket supposed to print out version,
#but it hangs here:
!racket -v
```

Anyone with a solution? any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket does not have any cell magic that can work out of the box, like for languages like Bash.
To run Racket on Jupyter, you can try using IRacket on your Jupyter notebook, which is still work in progress : https://github.com/rmculpepper/iracket

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab is supposed for working with IPython Notebooks only, there's no guarantees that Colab should work with other languages by writing to files and interpret or compile them.

C/C++ works with `%%writefile ...` and `%%script bash` to compile and run, but the machine instance in Colab somehow doesn't work with Racket: Racket hangs even before printing out anything, event the first character to stdout. Possibly Racket is missing some required stuff.

There's 1 suggestion is to use Paperspace.com, **Racket works well there,** but notice that Paperspace notebooks are all public. And from my experience, a Paperspace workspace is shared, not private, so files may be changed by others.